# I am not able to fetch the list value in Servlet using JsonArray

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am using the JSON array to get the values from Db in Servlet. I am suing following code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<ProjectDto> act=new ArrayList<ProjectDto>();
    act=ActivitiesDao.getActivitiesDetails();
    JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray();

    for(int i=0;i<act.size();i++)
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        //obj.put("issueno", quiz.get(i).getIssueno());
        obj.put("projectName",act.get(i).getProjectName());         
        obj.put("projectDescription",act.get(i).getProjectDescription());
        obj.put("currentStatus", act.get(i).getCurrentStatus());
        obj.put("area", act.get(i).getArea());          
        jsonarray.put(obj);
    }
    System.out.println("Json in Servelt"+ jsonarray.toString());        
    response.getWriter().print(jsonarray.toString());
    }
```

}

I am able to get value from DB successfully. I have printed value in console.

Now, I have defined one method in some other java file to convert the data in paragraphs. Now, I am calling that method in Servlet in following way:

//method:

```
    public static List<String> convertParagraphs(String text){

    List <String> convertedList= new ArrayList<String>();

    if(text==null|| text==""){

    }
    else{
    String[] paragraphs= text.split("\\|");

    convertedList= Arrays.asList(paragraphs);
    }
    return convertedList;

}
```

calling this method in Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<ProjectDto> act=new ArrayList<ProjectDto>();
    act=ActivitiesDao.getActivitiesDetails();
    JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray();



    for(int i=0;i<act.size();i++)
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("projectName",act.get(i).getProjectName());     
        String ttextt= act.get(i).getProjectDescription();
        obj.put("ProjectDescriptionList" , act.get(i).setProjectDescriptionList(NewsletterUtil.convertParagraphs(ttextt)));
        obj.put("currentStatus", act.get(i).getCurrentStatus());
        obj.put("area", act.get(i).getArea());
        obj.put("ProjectDescriptionList" , act.get(i).setProjectDescriptionList(NewsletterUtil.convertParagraphs(ttextt)));
        jsonarray.put(obj);

    }
    System.out.println("Json in Servelt"+ jsonarray.toString());

    response.getWriter().print(jsonarray.toString());
    }
```

}

Getters and Setters method:

```
public class ProjectDto {

private String projectName;
private String projectDescription;
private String currentStatus;
private String area;
private List<String> projectDescriptionList= new ArrayList<String>();

private List<String> currentStatusList=new ArrayList<String>();


public List<String> getCurrentStatusList() {
    return currentStatusList;
}
public void setCurrentStatusList(List<String> currentStatusList) {
    this.currentStatusList = currentStatusList;
}


public List<String> getProjectDescriptionList() {
    return projectDescriptionList;
}
public boolean setProjectDescriptionList(List<String> projectDescriptionList) {
    this.projectDescriptionList = projectDescriptionList;
    return false;
}
public String getCurrentStatus() {
    return currentStatus;
}
public void setCurrentStatus(String currentStatus) {
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
}
public String getArea() {
    return area;
}
public void setArea(String area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}
public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}
public String getProjectDescription() {
    return projectDescription;
}
public void setProjectDescription(String projectDescription) {
    this.projectDescription = projectDescription;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ProjectDto [projectName=" + projectName
            + ", projectDescription=" + projectDescription
            + ", currentStatus=" + currentStatus + ", area=" + area
            + ",  projectDescriptionList="
            + projectDescriptionList + "]";
}
```

}

Issue: Now, I am printing the value of ProjectDescription List, it is returning the false value. I am not sure where i am doing wrong. I tried to resolve the issues in many ways but not able to resolve the issue. could you please correct me and suggest me about my issue.

Please find my ajax code in jsp

```
    <script>
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ProjectServlet",
        success: function (responseText) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var uniueTabs = getUniqueLists(jsonData);

      for (var i = 0; i < uniueTabs.length; i++) {
           $('#tabs').append('<li ><a href="#tab-content-' + i + '">' + uniueTabs[i].area + '</a></li>');
            var div = '<div id="tab-content-' + i + '" class="tab-pane fade">';

            for (var j = 0; j < uniueTabs[i].tabContent.length; j++) {
                var obj = uniueTabs[i].tabContent[j];
                div += '<p>' + obj.projectName + '</p>'+  '<p>' + obj.projectDescription + '</p>' + obj.currentStatus   ;
    }

    $('.tab-content').append(div);
            $('#tab-content-0').addClass('in active');
           }

            $('#tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
        setListner();



    function getUniqueLists(responseText) {
        var resArr = [];
        responseText.filter(function (x, i) {
            if (resArr.indexOf(x.area) === -1) {
                resArr.push(x.area);
            }
        })
        //console.log(resArr);
        return mergeDataAreaWise(resArr, responseText);
    }

    function mergeDataAreaWise(area, responseText) {
        var tabList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
            tabList.push({
                area: area[i],
                tabContent: []
            });
        }
        var prjlist;
        var output; 
        var proh;

        var status;


        for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {            

          statuss = '<li>' + responseText[j].currentStatus + '</li>';
          prjlist= responseText[j].projectDescriptionList;


         /*  output= prjlist.split("&");
          proh=output.join("/n");
           */
          //proh=prjlist.replace(/&/g, '<br>');
          status =statuss.replace(/&/g, '<br>');

                var Obj = {

                    projectName: '<h3>'+ responseText[j].projectName +'</h3>',

                    projectDescription: '<p>'+ prjlist + '<p>',


                     currentStatus: '<b>'+ "Current Status:" +'</b>' + status 





                }


                   var currentArea = responseText[j].area;


                if (tabList[i].area === currentArea) {
                    tabList[i].tabContent.push(Obj);
                }
            }
        }


        console.log(tabList);
        return tabList;
    }



    }

    });
    function setListner () {
        $("#tabs a").click(function () {
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you will get the value as `false`.

in your setter you are returning a `boolean`, which does set the value of `projectDescriptionList` but finally returns the hard code `false` every time.

Solution,

In your getter-setter;

```
// optional, just stick to setter rules, set the value and don't return anything.

public setProjectDescriptionList(List<String> projectDescriptionList) {
    this.projectDescriptionList = projectDescriptionList;
}
```

In your `doPost` inside the for loop, third part of code in question

```
act.get(i).setProjectDescriptionList(NewsletterUtil.convertParagraphs(ttextt));
obj.put("ProjectDescriptionList" ,act.get(i).getProjectDescriptionList() );
obj.put("currentStatus", act.get(i).getCurrentStatus());
obj.put("area", act.get(i).getArea());
// I don't know why you wrote it twice.. I'm commenting it.
//   obj.put("ProjectDescriptionList" , act.get(i).setProjectDescriptionList(NewsletterUtil.convertParagraphs(ttextt)));
jsonarray.put(obj);
```

Comment: HI Manoj, Thank you for correcting me. Now, this code is working fine. Now, I am trying to access ProjectDescriptionList in ajax call, data is not getting splitted in new line. But now code for split data is fine. It is working fine using struts 2 tags.  but not working using ajax call. Now, it is showing data in commas(,). For eg: In DB i have put data like CSE| IT| ECE. Now, it is showing CSE, IT, ECE , . Could you please help me

Comment: HI Manoj, always you guided me..can you please help me to resolve my issue..I am in learning phase...so getting so many issues

Comment: @Rahul are you sure the database is having the values pipe separated i.e. (CSE | IT | CEC) etc.? also, avoid asking different question in same post, it is not recommended practice on SO community. People might raise a flag against your post which could result in deletion of all such posts and account may get suspended for a period as penalty . So avoid it.